# How do I model something like this?

Tags: java, object, modeling

I have this machine problem, and here is one of those tricky parts which gets me a little confused.

Here is the use case: 
Student enrolls in a section. 
System verifies no schedule conflicts.  
System verifies that the student has taken the required prerequisite(s).

So I created 4 objects, called Student, Section, Schedule, and Subject.
I'll only show you my "subject" class because this is where I got confused.

The part where I get confused is this: 
System verifies that the student has taken the required prerequisite(s).

How do I properly model that? 
I got a prerequisite which is a subject object, but what if the subject has no prerequisite? I hesitate because I cannot just make something like:

`Subject math01 = new Subject(1,"math01",null);`

I think passing null on objects is inappropriate. I'd like to avoid nullpointer exceptions. How do I resolve this? :(
I think I'm doing it wrong.

```
public class Subject {

    //Each subject is worth three (3) units.
    private int units = 3;

    private int subjectID;
    private String subjectName;
    private Subject prerequisite; //<----How do I express that a subject has a prerequisite? Am I doing this right?

    public Subject(int subjectID, String subjectName, Subject prerequisite) {
        this.subjectID = subjectID;
        this.subjectName = subjectName;
        this.prerequisite = prerequisite;
    }

    public int getUnits() {
        return units;
    }

    public int getSubjectID() {
        return subjectID;
    }

    public String getSubjectName() {
        return subjectName;
    }

    public Subject getPrerequisite(){
        return prerequisite;
    }

    public boolean conflictWith(Subject newSubject){
        return (this.subjectID == newSubject.getSubjectID());
    }

}
```

Comment: Instead of using `Subject prerequisite` use `Set<Subject> prerequisites`. If the set is empty, then the subject does not have any prerequisites.

Comment: Especially because subjects (/educational classes) may have more than one pre-req.  For best results, implement `.equals()` and `.hashcode()` (IDE defaults should be fine).

Comment: Thanks dude, that seems reasonable since a subject can have more than one prerequisites. And if the prerequisite size is 0 then it means it doesn't have any prerequisites. :D

Answer (score 0):

Consider adding a second constructor that doesn't take a prerequisite. Then you don't have to pass in null from the client of your API.

I'd also add a convenience method hasPrerequisite() for checking to see if the Subject does have a prerequisite. That way clients of your API also don't have to do a null check themselves.

Answer (score -1):

Use [Null Object pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_Object_pattern). My recommendation is for you to use [Guava library](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/) so that you can use the [Optional](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/base/Optional.html) class. [Here is the tutorial](http://java.dzone.com/articles/guavas-new-optional-class) explaining its usage.